# Error restaurar copia Método obsoleto getExternalStorageDirectory() en Android API 29 en adelante

Tags: java, android

Este es el código de mi aplicación Android. Cuando le doy al botón de ImportarFicheroABaseDatos() me da error. Este es mi método de Importar y de Exportar y dejo una imagen de donde coloco mi base de datos para importarla.

En versiones anteriores de Android esto funcionaba sin ningún problema, al actualizar al sdk 33 es donde me esta dando este problema y no se muy bien como arreglarlo.

He leído que el método de getExternalStorageDirectory se ha quedado obsoleto pero no se como modificar mi aplicación para que funcione igual modificando eso.

```
public void ImportarFicheroABaseDatos(){
        try{
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            String packageName = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();


            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//" + packageName + RUTA_SQLITE_BD;
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, RUTA_FICHERO_BD + "" + ".db");

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Copia sustituida correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            //Iñaki lo añade por el tema de los permisos y las copias de seguridad. Para ello se ha puesto la linea android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" en el manifiesto.
            else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error al comprobar los permisos para sustituir la copia de seguridad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error al importar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void ExportarBaseDatosAFichero(String sufijo) throws Exception{
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        String packageName = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + packageName + RUTA_SQLITE_BD;
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, RUTA_FICHERO_BD + sufijo + ".db");

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Base de datos que quiero importar]

Answer (score 0):

si tu app esa compilada con un TargetSDK = 29 (Android 10) o posterior, ya no podrás hacer uso de `getExternalFilesDir()`, ahora usa:

> **[getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))** Devuelve la ruta absoluta al directorio en el dispositivo de
> almacenamiento externo/compartido principal donde la aplicación puede
> colocar los archivos persistentes que posee.

```
 //File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   File sd = getExternalFilesDir(null);
```